# Can't start unattended import of azure database with powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to start import of azure sql database using powershell.Since I want this to run during deployment I can't use the Get-Credential since I will get a login prompt with that.

```
Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile $publishSettingsFile
Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $subscriptionName -Certificate $certificate
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $subscriptionName
$databaseContext = New-AzureSqlDatabaseServerContext -ServerName $serverName -UseSubscription
$storageContext = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName testdatabasebackups -StorageAccountKey $storageKey

Start-AzureSqlDatabaseImport -SqlConnectionContext $databaseContext -StorageContainer $storageContainer -DatabaseName $databaseName -BlobName $restoreFrom
```

When I get to `Start-AzureSqlDatabaseImport` I get the following error:

Start-AzureSqlDatabaseImport : Cannot bind parameter 'SqlConnectionContext'. Cannot convert the "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.SqlDatabase.Services.Server.ServerDataServiceCertAuth" value of type "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.SqlDatabase.Services.Serve
r.ServerDataServiceCertAuth" to type "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.SqlDatabase.Services.Server.ISqlServerConnectionInformation".

Is it possible to do it this way or do I need to use `Get-Credential` when using `Start-AzureSqlDatabaseImport`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For using the PowerShell `Start-AzureSQLDatabaseImport`, you will need to use Get-Credential to create the new server context with SQL Server authentication. 
The reason this is required is that the Import cmdlet requires SQL Server authentication to access the server.

To establish the SQL Server authentication as part of your server connection context you will need to provide PowerShell credentials.

Get the latest version of Azure PowerShell installed [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-tools/releases) then you can try the following:

1. `Add-AzureAccount`
2. `Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName 'SubscriptionName'`
3. `$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString 'MyPassowrd' -AsPlainText -Force`
4. `$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList 'LoginName', $Password`
5. `$SqlCtx = New-AzureSqlDatabaseServerContext -ServerName 'ServerName' -Credential $cred`
6. `$StorageCtx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName 'StorageAccountName' -StorageAccountKey 'YourStorageKey'`
7. `$Container = Get-AzureStorageContainer -Name 'ContainerName'`
8. `$ImportRequest = Start-AzureSqlDatabaseImport -SqlConnectionContext $SqlCtx -StorageContainer $Container -BlobName 'BlobFileName'`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I modified your example to not do Add-AzureAccount and added ctx to the Get-AzureStorageContainer call and it worked.